# TypeScript refactoring stopped working in VS 2013 RC2

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have just installed VS 2013 RC2 and TypeScript refactoring stopped working. It disappeared from context menu, and pressing `Ctrl+R`, `Ctrl+R` gives the following error message:

> The key combination (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R) is bound to command (.Refactor.Rename) which is not currently available.

I have tried restarting VS, didn't help. Any ideas, workarounds?

**Edit:**
I have submitted a bug to Microsoft. Please upvote it if you have the same issue:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/860463/typescript-refactoring-stopped-working-in-vs-2013-rc2

Comment: Have you made sure that in Add/Remove programs that all old plugins/extensions for TypeScript were removed? I had a few problems with TypeScript integration when a few of them were still installed. I know `F2` on my installation still does a rename for TypeScript. But, it also appears in the context menu on my system.

Comment: I removed it, but didn't work unfortunatelly. Thank you though.

Comment: Is everything else working? If so, submit a bug in Microsoft's Connect web site.

Comment: Yes. I have uninstalled VS 2013, deleted Visual Studio 12.0 directory from program files, reinstalled it with Update 2 RC, still the same.

Comment: And you've tried using the `F2` key for rename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft posted the following answer to [my question on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/860463/typescript-refactoring-stopped-working-in-vs-2013-rc2). Seems that while refactor/rename was available in VS Express Edition with TypeScript 0.9, in TypeScript 1.0 it's only available from VS Pro upwards.

> Posted by Microsoft on 19/05/2014 at 09:25
>
> Thank you for reporting this issue.
>
> Refactor/rename and NavigateTo are features that are found in the Pro+
>   versions of TypeScript in Visual Studio 2013. The Pro+ tools are aimed
>   at helping users work with larger codebases, so there is a focus on
>   building up tools to help support those codebases in those versions of
>   Visual Studio. We're working to continue to refine to make the
>   experience best across both Express and Pro+, with the right features
>   to help users who want to learn TypeScript and those who want to move
>   to using TypeScript in larger projects.

Answer (score 1):

For me it happened because of resharper conflict. I uninstalled resharper and restarted visual studio

Comment: I don't have and never had Resharper installed.